# Installing aws for asp.net in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis, amazon-web-services

I am not very experienced in asp.net. I am working on an old classic asp site and have in the past added small bits of asp.net c# to do things I can't do in classic asp. I had been doing this by just writing single pages with aspx extension and all is good.

I now want to add some functionality from Amazon's AWS. However, I can't work out how to tell IIS to use Amazon's AWS libraries. I'm assuming it's something to do with "system.web/compilation" and the list of assemblies, but I can't work out what the correct syntax might be for AWS. Can't find it anywhere!! Help!

Comment: You can add the AWS*.dll to your bin or to GAC

Comment: Thanks! Adding those files to a bin folder at the root of the website did the trick! Couldn't find gacutil on my machine though to do it globally.